# Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing: model validation

Tags: r, data-science

I want to run this code for model Validation and I am getting the error in the train()

```
library(caret)
diabet<-read.csv("C:/Users/Downloads/diabetes.csv")
diabet$Outcome<-as.factor(diabet$Outcome)
diabet$BMI<-as.factor(diabet$BMI)
train_control<- trainControl(method="boot", number=100)
model <-train(diabet$Outcome~diabet$BMI, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
print(model)
```

I am getting this type error

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :2     NA's   :2    
Error: Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

can any one help me out how can I fix the error?

Comment: The error that you're getting isn't even from `print(model)`, it's from the `train()` itself. Remove the print and you will still get the stopping message. I've posted an answer to why that is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train), there are two ways to call the `train()`:

```
## S3 method for class 'default':
train(x, y, 
      method = "rf",  
      ..., 
      weights = NULL,
      metric = ifelse(is.factor(y), "Accuracy", "RMSE"),   
      maximize = ifelse(metric == "RMSE", FALSE, TRUE),
      trControl = trainControl(), 
      tuneGrid = NULL, 
      tuneLength = 3)

## S3 method for class 'formula':
train(form, data, ..., weights, subset, na.action, contrasts = NULL)
```

From your question post, it looks like you're attempting to use the second signature, so this is how you should be implementing it:

```
model <-train(Outcome~BMI, data=diabet, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
```

This way you have a valid formula for `form`, and you also pass in the required `data` in the function call.